# Why are Chrome and Opera not showing content?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, opera

So I seem to be having this issue on a couple of sites now and only in Chrome (36.0.1985.125 m) and Opera (23.0.1522.60). Firefox, IE, Safari and even Chrome Canary are working as expected.

#### The problem

Most of the content isn't being shown, sometimes only a logo is visible, the background color is also always. Those pages have also gotten quite long and at around half the page I always get a black background that continues all the way to the bottom.

The content does seem to appear (unstyled) for a split second when I quickly refresh the page.

Here's a gif of what's happening. First I quickly refresh the page a couple of times, then I start scrolling down:

[image: Example screenshots]

Does anyone have any idea about why this is happening? It might be a CSS3 issue because this particular website always showcases cutting-edge CSS3 features, but they should definitely be working in Chrome (as reported by others). Anyway, that's just speculation.

The page: [CoDrops article](http://tympanus.net/Development/NotificationStyles/)

Comment: Could be graphics drivers. You could try disabling hardware acceleration or updating your drivers.

Comment: I already tried turning off hardware acceleration in Opera, didn't do the trick. Also, Firefox has it turned on and it displays the page just fine.

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you use the [incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en) or a [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable)?

Comment: Yeah, same issue for both incognito and portable. Funny though, the portable apps website seems to be another website that's not displaying content, so definitely not a CSS3 issue. I'm gonna try to update my graphics drivers now.

Comment: Ah, there we go. A driver update fixed the issues. Thanks for the help guys.